# ASP.Net application is not breaking on break point

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0, breakpoints

All of sudden my application is not breaking on the break point. I have tried the solutions given in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856643/why-would-the-debugger-not-be-stopping-at-a-breakpoint-in-my-asp-net-application) but of no use.

PS: However, it is breaking on the default.aspx

[image]

Comment: We're going to need more information. Where are you setting the breakpoint? Can you post code?

Comment: More information is needed, for example: is that breakpoint in code that is the web app assembly or some other assembly ? And are you *sure* that this code is actually executing ? Are you using web application or web site project type ?

Comment: @James: I have attached the image

Comment: Thats a pretty exhaustive list there and none of them worked for you

Comment: @Antonio: Its web application. The code is executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone.

One of my senior developer had solved the issue. The problem was, invalid port number.

- The solution is to Change project property `Use dynamic ports` from `True` to `False`.

Since the port was set as dynamic, it was changing dynamically & the flex application was referring the different port fetching data from there.

Answer (score 1):

The main things to check are:

1) full solution rebuilt ok?

2) Dev iis/casini server running ok? restart them potential

3) Debug build?

4) UI code calling the required web service method?

5) Attached to the correct process if manually attaching for debug?

6) Close Visual Studio and re-open solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try breaking on line 41 instead?