# Visual Studio 2010 remote debugging: Debugging symbols are not loaded for this document

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, remote-debugging

This is a weird problem, which luckily (?) also happens on other machines.

I've never had problems with debugging, and now I have: it shows an exclamation mark at my breakpoints which says :'The debugging symbols are not loaded for this document'.

The difference with other projects is that I run this web application in IIS:

- I've created a new website in IIS 7.5 (win7), listening on port 80 to
  local.comparer.nl
- I've added the url local.comparer.nl to my hosts
  file, redirecting it to 127.0.0.1
- I've edited the start page of the
  project (asp.net 3.5) to local.comparer.nl in 'use local IIS
  webserver'

When I start the site, it first says 'unable to start remote debugging'. I don't know why it looks for remote debugging, but when I started the remote debugging monitor, it still didn't work.

When I unloaded the debugging monitor, it didn't complain about the remote debugging anymore, but the exclamation mark still was there.

Solutions which -sometimes- help at my colleagues pc's:

- Delete everything from the \bin directory and rebuild
- Rebuild again (n number of times)
- Choose 'clean solution'

Any idea?

Comment: Check this helps: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856643/why-would-the-debugger-not-be-stopping-at-a-breakpoint-in-my-asp-net-application), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746607/asp-net-application-is-not-breaking-on-break-point/6747820#6747820)

Comment: thanks, in link1 they say what they tried here: delete everything, clean everyting etc. That -sometimes- works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you building full debugging symbols? If not then the debugger has no information to relate the source code to the in memory activity under the debugger. This is set in the project properties per configuration.

Also ensure the symbols are in the `bin` folder.

You can validate that VS is loading the right symbols with the Debug | Modules window.

Comment: yes, i have the pdb files. What do you mean with 'full' debugging symbols? Are there multiple kinds?

Comment: @Michel: There are two types: full and "pdb-only". The latter includes function entry points, the former adds information down to source code lines.

Comment: WHOW! that works! Gonna tell my colleagues too! Thanks VERY VERY (did i mention VERY?) much. They were deleting and recompiling all the time, but i am new on the project, and in a project with loads of repeaters and innerrepeaters, i can't live without debug.... Thanks again! (and funny: had NEVER opened the little window where you can say 'full')

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue bothering me for quite long. Finally, what resolved my problem is :-

1) Make Internet Explorer the default browser
2) Clean the solution
3) Build the solution

Answer (score 0):

In my case I renamed an asp.net page and disconnected the code behind. Strange it still ran but did not run the code behind and therefore did not hit breakpoints in it.

Answer (score -2):

You have to in Visual Studio 2010

1. Select "Build" Meanu > Clean [Project/Solution Name]
2. Rebuild [Project/Solution]

Try debug again... Good luck