# Trouble loading symbols Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

## RESOLVED

The problem was in how Visual Studio was running the website.  I had stupidly misconfigured my properties; I hadn't set `Use Local IIS Web Server` like I should have.

---

I'm getting the dreaded

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

while trying to debug my asp.net MVC 3 application.  Following the advice [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/dbutscher/archive/2007/06/26/113472.aspx), I hit F5 to debug, went to `debug -> windows -> modules`, but my website's dll *doesn't even show up*.  I should see a `Services.Web.UI.Mvc.dll`, but I don't.  It seems *nothing* outside of the built-in .net assemblies are being loaded.

Does anyone know what I can do to get my website's symbols loaded?

[image]

Comment: Are you running the site locally or is this like a remote debug situation?

Comment: @SwDevMan81 - running the site locally, but it is configured to run through IIS.  Not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: Looks like some helpful tips [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856643/why-would-the-debugger-not-be-stopping-at-a-breakpoint-in-my-asp-net-application)

Comment: Why not post the resolution as an answer and accept it?  I don't think you get points for it but the question would at least be marked as answered :)

Comment: Good point, @Jared.  Done.  (or completely done in two days when I can accept it)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in how Visual Studio was running the website. I had stupidly misconfigured my properties; I hadn't set Use Local IIS Web Server like I should have.