# Web method not getting hit but ajax success says it is

Tags: javascript, asp.net

**Update**
If I use Fiddler, I see I get a 200 OK Response but the following message:

> {"Message":"Authentication
>   failed.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

I have no idea where that's coming from.

**Original Post**
When I place a breakpoint in the web method it is never hit. The success handler runs for the ajax call. If I change the name of the url to incorrect value, I do get an error in F12 tools that it is not found.

I've tried `EnablePageMethods='true'` as well on the `ScriptManager`.

JavaScript lives in Scripts folder

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Tasks.aspx/UpdateStatus',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: '{ id: 8, status: 1 }',
    success: function (data) {
        alert('it worked!');
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

Tasks.aspx.cs code behind

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string UpdateStatus(int id, int status)
{
    TaskManager taskManager = new TaskManager();
    taskManager.UpdateStatus((TaskStatuses)status, id);
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Did you connect to the correct process? Is the build the same in your IDE as the executing process (this can cause breakpoints not to be hit). In your c# code add `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();`, this will force a prompt asking you if you want to attach your IDE to debug the code.

Comment: I would suggest you edit the title of this question to "Debugger not stopping on breakpoint" and include the development product/version that you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would the debugger not be stopping at a breakpoint in my ASP.NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856643/why-would-the-debugger-not-be-stopping-at-a-breakpoint-in-my-asp-net-application)

Comment: The failure is occurring before the web method is executed, during the authentication step. For example, there could be a problem parsing your token. ASP.NET will not pass control to the web method in this scenario.

Comment: Agree with John Wu. You might need to call a new service-method that checks if the user is authenticated first (return a bool). You could also try adding `data: JSON.stringify({  "id": 8, "status": 1  })`, or just the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing `PageMethod` in the code-behind to a `web service asmx` file and that seemed to have worked. Now I have to figure out how to secure it.