# Why does Visual Studio start my web app in non-debug mode if IE8 is already opened?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, internet-explorer

**Problem**

If *IE8* is already opened then my app will be started in non-debug mode rather than debug mode. Visual Studio "lets go of it".

Why that is and how to change it?

**Expected and Desired Behaviour**

With my previous installation if *IE7* wasn't running, Visual Studio would start *IE7* and load the application into a new tab. If IE was running Visual Studio would simply pop a fresh tab into the currently running instance. Either way I "always" got debug mode when i asked for it.

**Environment**

using: *Visual Studio 2005/ IE 8*

Project Properties: Servers: Use Visual Studio Development Server is ticked.

**Edit**

*Problem is IE8/VS2005 specific.* See XpiritO links for the answer and also follow [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/askie/archive/2009/03/09/opening-a-new-tab-may-launch-a-new-process-with-internet-explorer-8-0.aspx) msdn blog link for additional information about the registry fix and what you are actually doing when using that method to resolve the problem. As i understand it, you're essentially killing off the benefits of the new Loosely Coupled IE (LCIE) framework of IE8 by setting TabProcGrowth=0, which may or may not be a desirable trade off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663144/why-cant-i-debug-from-visual-studio-2005-after-installing-ie8) what you're looking for?

EDIT: You can also try [this](http://dpotter.net/Technical/2009/05/upgrading-to-ie8-breaks-debugging-with-visual-studio-2005/).

Comment: That's the ticket. I did a machine rebuild about 6 months ago and upgraded to IE8 at the time. Prior to that I had IE7. I also installed VS2008. So I wasn't absolutely sure where the problem lay. It was never a big deal but I figured Id finally resolve it.  So thanks a bunch.