# Break point is not getting Hit with IE8

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005, internet-explorer-8

I am Using visual studio 2005 and web browser IE8. On debugging the code opened in IE8 ,the 
Breakpoints are not getting hit. Using IE6 I am able to debug. but i don't want to use IE6
so can you suggest any solution???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer here :-
[Why can't I debug from Visual Studio 2005 after installing IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663144/why-cant-i-debug-from-visual-studio-2005-after-installing-ie8)