# How to debug a managed BHO from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, com-interop, bho

I've a managed Explorer Bar (working in Internet Explorer) that is working reasonably well. Currently, the only way to debug it:

1. Start IE outside VS
2. From VS (Debug => Attach) Attach to the process "iexplore.exe"

Trying to do the following:

1. Go to Project Properties => Debug tab
2. Start External Program: *c:\program files (x86)\internet explorer\iexplore.exe*
3. Command line argument: about:blank
4. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd>

The first method is very cumbersome. With the second method, iexplore starts, but the debugger doesn't recognize the breakpoints, don't know why.

Any tip?

Comment: What happens in the second method?

Comment: @gideon, with the second method, iexplore starts, but debugger doesn't recognize the breakpoints.

Comment: edited/updated your question, you don't need html for format lists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I debug from Visual Studio 2005 after installing IE8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663144/why-cant-i-debug-from-visual-studio-2005-after-installing-ie8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So ... 3 months after I opened this question, here is the answer.
In Visual Studio, open an EXE as a new project:

1. File -> Open -> Project/Solution
2. Change type to exe file
3. Open c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe

then, open project property:

1. There is only one 'General' tab
2. Change Debugger Type to 'Managed v4.0'

That's it. <kbd>F5</kbd> will now work. You can add this EXE project to the solution that contains your managed bho, and set the EXE project to be the Startup project.