# Visual Studio web load test tool add on

Tags: visual-studio-2013, internet-explorer-10, add-on, ieaddon

I am trying to run Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate tool to run Web Performance test. My IE10 browser keeps prompting to enable the following add on. I keep clicking the enable button but nothing happens. This dialog just stays there. I try to enable this add on from the manage-addon screen but my enable/disable buttons are greyed out. How do I enable this addon?

[image]
[image]

Comment: you are having two visual studio installed ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug a managed BHO from Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629976/how-to-debug-a-managed-bho-from-visual-studio-2010)